# Estoy intentando desplegar mi app en heroku desde la terminal git CMD desde Windows

Tags: python, git, heroku

la aplicacion que quiero subir es hecha en python-django nose si importe pero uso el framework bulma

al hacer el deploy me sale este error, GTK esta instalado

```
remote:            checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
remote:            checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
remote:            checking for GTK+ - version >= 3.0.0... Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:            Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
remote:            to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:            No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
remote:            no
remote:            *** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
remote:            *** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
remote:            *** exact error that occurred. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
remote:            configure: error:
remote:            The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
remote:            ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
remote:            installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
remote:            and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
remote:            libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
remote:            --libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.
remote:
```

e intentado todas las formas de hacer el deploy al parecer no es ese el problema

ya instale GTK-3.0 y puse la ruta en el path

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

tambien puse esta otra ruta en el path que es donde se encuentra el pkg-config

```
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions
```

en mi archivo requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
decouple==0.0.7
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.5
django-bulma==0.8.2
django-static-fontawesome==5.14.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.2
MouseInfo==0.1.3
numpy==1.21.1
Pillow==8.3.1
psycopg2==2.9.1
PyAutoGUI==0.9.53
PyGetWindow==0.0.9
PyMsgBox==1.0.9
pyperclip==1.8.2
PyRect==0.1.4
PyScreeze==0.1.27
PyTweening==1.0.3
pytz==2021.1
pywhatkit==5.1
requests==2.26.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
urllib3==1.26.6
webcolors==1.11.1
whitenoise==5.3.0
wikipedia==1.4.0
wxPython==4.1.1
wxwidgets==1.0.5
```

Comment: que lenguaje?..

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: que tienes en tu archivo `requeriments.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

por si alquien tiene el mismo problema lo arregle eliminando

```
wxPython==4.1.1
wxwidgets==1.0.5
```

despues de eso no me aparecio el mismo error, recuerden hacer el git add -A y el commit ect antes de hacer el deploy de nuevo